# How to remove clear button from datetime-local?

Tags: javascript, html, datetimepicker

I have used `datetime-local` input type in webview (Android Application).
It shows `cancel` `clear` and `set` button.Is there any way to remove `clear` button from date time picker?

```
 <center><input type="datetime-local"  name="start date"  ng-model="startDateTime" id="to_date"></center>
```

Comment: which one you are saying as a clear button?

Comment: actually on date time picker window.there are three button as I say "Cancel","clear" and "set" button I want to hide or remove "clear" button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be possible to apply normal web CSS to the contents of a Webview if you have access to those contents:

```css
input[type="datetime-local"]::-webkit-clear-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
 }
```

```html
<input type="datetime-local" defaultValue="2017-06-01T08:30" required>
```

EDIT: I believe this method^ hid the clear button inside the input (which perhaps no longer exists) - not the clear button inside the popover. It is possible this solution is no longer relevant in current browsers. The `required` attribute should be the correct solution here but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

Comment: this doesn't seem to work

Comment: i agree, if I recall correctly, my solution hid the 'clear' button inside the input (which doesn't seem to exist anymore). I have added a warning to the answer.